# React svg QR codes when multiple shown in a single page. Library qr-code-styling

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm using the qr-code-styling library in a React project to create svg Qr Codes. The problem is that if there are multiple QR Codes displayed on the page and when I change the style of one specific QR Code, it applies to all QR Codes and not to a single one. This is due to the same IDs in the SVG. How can I solve this problem? How to uniqueize ID for each SVG which generate qr-code-styling?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The qr-code-styling library offers a few configuration options.

To circumvent the SVG ID's clashing you can change the "type" property to "canvas" in the options like so:

```
new QRCodeStyling({
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100,
  "shape": 'square',
  "data": 'https://google.com',
  "type": "canvas"
});
```